# Do popular browser firefox / chrome / IE / opera compress HTTP requests (e.g. HTTP POST request)

Tags: browser, http

If I send a large POST request via any of the popular browsers, will it automatically compress and send it (assuming that the server also supports compressed content). How will the browser know beforehand that the server supports or not. I didn't see any of this clearly documented so far. Thanks for any inputs